# React-Native: Math between state variables

Tags: react-native, state

I'm trying to add one state variable to the like here in the example:

```
state= {
NumberA: 1, NumberB: 3, Result: NumberA+NumberB};
```

I'm using Expo for the testing and the Picker which chooses the numbers.

Is there a way to add the numbers in or out of state brackets or is there a other way for the Picker, because I tried but then the selected number isn't displaying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.states = {
    NumberA:1,
    NumberB:4,
    result:null
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
//update result now
 this.setState({result:this.state.NumberA + this.state.NumberB});

}
```

If your NumberA and NumberB states are set, you can get result without any third state

```
let result = this.state.NumberA + this.state.NumberB
```

Comment: Thank you four you anwser, it works now fine